# getting variable after ajax load with the new dom elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I have content loaded with AJAX and I need to know the value of a variable to use for events on the loaded dom elements.

This is my code:

```
var course_select  = $(this).closest('div[id^=course-]').attr('id'); 
// get the course id
var course_id = course_select.split('-')[1]; // get the number
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'main/ajaxjson/load_course_details',
        data: {page : which, course_id: course_id},
        success: function(home){

            $('#ajax-content-' + course_id).hide();
            $('#ajax-content-' + course_id).empty().append(home);
            $('#ajax-content-' + course_id).fadeIn();
})`
```

I get the new loaded content and after that I bind events like this:
`$('body').on('click',param_here, function_here(){});`

I need course_id variable to be available to access it with the new elements.

Comment: Why not put the course ID in the class name of the returned elements? That will make is quite easy to select them.

Comment: what do you mean in the class name?

Comment: <div class="ajax-content-12'>...</div> then you can query the content by class name. All of the elements with the same class name can be selected if you know the ID.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a variable before your `.ajax()`, and set it in your success method.
But you would never know at runtime if the ajax has been completely done, or more specific you don't know when your var `courseId` is set.
So what you could do is change the value of your variable, and then trigger a custom event like so `$(body).trigger('courseIdUpdate');`
And all you would have to do is listen for that event like:

```
$(body).on('courseIdUpdate',function(){
    alert("My course Id has been updated");
    //run additional code that needs the updated courseId
});
```

It is a bit much work for a simple task but maybe you should consider this.